# Python. Hashlib. Как преобразовать строку с хэшем в md5 hash object?

Tags: python-3.x, хеширование, md5

Хочу ускорить брут паролей по словарю. Сейчас над каждым словом выполняется `hashlib.md5(word.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`. Как мне преобразовать искомый хэш в md5 hash object, что бы отбросить `.hexdigest()` и производить сравнение между двумя md5 hash object, а не между шестнадцатеричными строками?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете сравнивать объекты hash, они для этого не предназначены. Что бы не конвертировать хеши в hex, вы можете сравнивать массивы байт таким образом:

```
search = bytes.fromhex('d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4')
hash = hashlib.md5('qwerty'.encode('utf-8')).digest()
print(search == hash)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. попробовал. этот способ немногим быстрее, до строки 2599720 доходит за 3,3 секунды против 3,4 если сравнивать c hex. буду копать в другом направлении)))

Comment: @YSOFF питон не очень подходит для такого